# I cant add Firebase library in flutter project

Tags: android, firebase, flutter

I'm using flutter to develop an application. I added firebase to my project, after that when I running the app, some error appears in the debug console. I removed the firebase library but I got an error again for other libraries.

> Note: I don't use Android X

build.gradle:

```
 repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.1'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.2'
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
}
```

bulild.gradle(app)

```
compileSdkVersion 28

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.6.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.8'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

- Error running Gradle:
  ProcessException: Process "E:\Mehrdad Omidi\Project\flutter\smart new\behroob\android\gradlew.bat" exited abnormally:
  Configure project :app
  WARNING: API 'variant.getJavaCompile()' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'variant.getJavaCompileProvider()'.
  It will be removed at the end of 2019.
  For more information, see https://d.android.com/r/tools/task-configuration-avoidance.
  To determine what is calling variant.getJavaCompile(), use -Pandroid.debug.obsoleteApi=true on the command line to display more information.
  WARNING: API 'variant.getMergeAssets()' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'variant.getMergeAssetsProvider()'.
  It will be removed at the end of 2019.
  For more information, see https://d.android.com/r/tools/task-configuration-avoidance.
  To determine what is calling variant.getMergeAssets(), use -Pandroid.debug.obsoleteApi=true on the command line to display more information.
  WARNING: API 'variantOutput.getProcessResources()' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'variantOutput.getProcessResourcesProvider()'.
  It will be removed at the end of 2019.
  For more information, see https://d.android.com/r/tools/task-configuration-avoidance.
  To determine what is calling variantOutput.getProcessResources(), use -Pandroid.debug.obsoleteApi=true on the command line to display more information.
       *********************************************************
  WARNING: This version of google_maps_flutter will break your Android build if it or its dependencies aren't compatible with AndroidX.
       See .... for more information on the problem and how to fix it.
       This warning prints for all Android build failures. The real root cause of the error may be unrelated.
       *********************************************************
  Command: E:\Mehrdad Omidi\Project\flutter\smart new\behroob\android\gradlew.bat app:properties

  Finished with error: Please review your Gradle project setup in the android/ folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

open android directory and then right click on it and go to flutter>Open Android module ,then in new window that is opened fix bugs and close window then comeback to flutter.